# Build .apk file from lua files

Tags: android, lua

For my business we outsourced the building of our Android App to an outside contractor, and he recently came back to us with the finished product. When I got the app I found out that it was all in Lua, when I was expecting it to be in Java, which is not a big deal, however I did not receive the .apk file from the developer. The only problem is I now don't know what to do with these files because I am unsure as to how I turn these files into a .apk file that can be distributed onto the Google Play store. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you mean your android app's source code is written in `lua` ?

Comment: The contractor probably has some own multi-platform solution that turns lua files into an app. The lua files are probably useless to you

Comment: farmer - Yeah, it looks like it, all the files are .lua files. 
Ivo - So then is there a solution? I'd like my own developers to be able to edit the files in the future

Comment: https://github.com/mkottman/AndroLua

Comment: Your contractor should have provided build instructions to go with the sources, and those instructions should have named any 3rd party tools or frameworks. In his shoes, I personally would have discussed the choice of framework with my customer early on, because that choice will affect long term support, may have legal implications, and especially to avoid this kind of surprise on "delivery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of tools which let you create android apps in lua. One of which is [Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/). I'm sure a few searches will find others.

To ask a stupid question... is this not something you can ask the contractor about?

Comment: I've attempted contacting the contractor, however he's been a little slow with responding in the past, so I figured I would ask here and see if I could expedite the process. But it sounds like I should probably wait for him to get back to me so that I can find out what tools he used.

Comment: The contents of the lua files might very well give you clues as to what was used to build the app. I would look for any requires() calls that don't map to anything in the source and/or any comment reference to an external library and start digging from there.